# How to Simulate click to click a website button in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to learn how to Simulate click. For example, clicking 'Search' button in Bing. Now I have assigned the Value to be searched in the Search Box but how to Simulate click on Search button.

Here is my Code

```
private async void Button_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var httpClint = new HttpClient();
        var elements = await httpClint.GetStringAsync(new Uri("https://www.bing.com/"));
        var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(elements);
        var node1 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("input").Where(p => p.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "b_searchbox").ToArray();
        node1[0].Attributes[5].Value = InputText.Text;            
        var node2 = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("input").Where(p => p.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "b_searchboxSubmit").ToArray();
}
```

I know how to do it on WPF. I want a code equivalent to

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ID").InvokeMember("click");
```

for UWP

Comment: You have to write javascript and invoke it in buttonclick(If you  are using webview)

Comment: @Archana is there is any other way without using javascript? Because in WPF we can use InvokeMember so there should be an alternative to it in UWP.

Comment: I dont think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what your want with HtmlDocument. This is a static HTML DOM tree where the javascript is not active. 
In your WPF you seem to be using the [webview control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx) (webBrower1) and not an HTML document.

The equivalent of WPF WebBrowser in UWP is [WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView). You can load it from an HTTP request and invoke JS scripts.

You can either invoke a script from the page or any arbitrary JS code by invoking the `eval` function and providing your function code as parameter.

In the following code, I'm initiating a search on the word 'bing' once the Bing home page is loaded.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    webview.NavigationCompleted += OnNavigationCompleted;
    webview.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
}

private async void OnNavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    webview.NavigationCompleted -= OnNavigationCompleted;

    var inputValue = "Bing";

    var functionString = string.Format(@"document.getElementsByClassName('b_searchbox')[0].innerText = '{0}';
                                        document.getElementsByClassName('b_searchboxSubmit')[0].click();", inputValue);
    await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { functionString });
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer by adding some code samples? I have never used JS scripts in C#

Comment: I've added a sample to my answer